# map function for ruby tree class

Tags: ruby, dictionary, tree

How would I write a map function for an n-ary tree in ruby?

```
class Tree
  def children() return @children end 
  def label() return @label end 

  def initialize(label, children)
    @label = label
    @children = children
  end 

  def map(&block)
     # TODO
  end
end
```

(Notice `children` is an arbitrary list (not necessarily of length <= 2).)

I want to write a function: `map(&block)`, which applies `block` to every subtree of the given tree (including the tree itself). That is, `block` will take in a `Tree` and return some object of arbitrary type `B`. The result of the map will be a `Tree` with labels of type `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can implement an `each` method for your class, then `include Enumerable`, you'll inherit all sorts of magical goodness including `map`.

Implement `<=>` and you'll gain even more.

[Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) is your friend.

---

EDIT:

If you look at what happens when `Hash#map` is called, the hash is transformed into an array of arrays:

```
>> hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2} #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
>> hash.map{|n| n} #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

It is up to the developer to mop-up afterward and optionally rebuild the transformed hash. It's easy because of how `Hash[]` works.

```
>> Hash[*hash.map{|n| n}.flatten] #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

If it was me, I'd write a way to take an array of arrays, and rebuild your tree. That way your `each` method would allow you to `include Enumerable` which would create `map`. You could call it, and then rebuild the tree on the fly. Look at how `Hash#[]` is used and you should be on your way to implementing something similar for your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The result of the map is not a tree. Can you be more explicit in your solution?

Comment: Implementing an `each` depends on the internal structure of your class.  Your sample code doesn't show how you are building your tree, or what you are basing it on. Without that information there is no way to provide more.

Comment: I want to implement `each` such that, for example, when I construct a tree, `t`, of floats (each `label` is a float and `children` is an array of such trees) I can call `t.map{|x| -x.label}` would return a new tree, identical to `t`, but where the value at each label would be negated. How do I define `each` to work like that?

Comment: @dsg, see my edit for a possible way to get where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
def map(&block)
    Tree.new(block.call(self), children.map{|x| x.map(&block)})    
end
```

Here's an example usage:

```
t.map{|x| puts(x.label + " -> " + x.children.map{|i| i.label}.join(" "))}
```

For every node in the tree, this local tree information in the form:

```
<label> -> <child label 1> <child label 2> <child label 3>
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question or trying to extend the original question? If extending it, then please re-edit your original question and delete this answer.

Comment: So your answer is in contention with ours? Sounds like an easy win.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing block.call(), you can also just yield:

```
  def map(&block)
    yield self
    children.each {|child| child.map(&block)}
  end
```

Comment: Ugh.  You're right.  That's what I get for rushing an answer.  Thanks for catching that.  (Can't believe I got a vote for that!)